# Virtual consoles (Linux–FreeBSD): possibly mistaken closure

Tags: support, duplicate, reopen-closed

When I was about to write a post about Linux–FreeBSD virtual *consoles* and their difference from virtual *terminals*, an anomaly surfaced.

The question [Computer terminal and virtual console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17810/computer-terminal-and-virtual-console) asked namely this thing; note the second Wikipedia quote. But it was dumped into [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) that considers such thing as:

- terminal
- shell
- tty
- console

and nothing about **virtual** consoles, that is a special concept deserving some attention.

IMHO closing users were misled by confusing (and largely off-topical) answers to the former question, and made a wrong decision to close as duplicate. **Could anybody help with reopening?** If it’s impractical, then Ī̲ could leave my post under “What is the exact…”, but the thread is already overcomplicated.

---

Now posted at

- [How are virtual consoles related to traditional computer terminals?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228050/how-are-virtual-consoles-related-to-traditional-computer-terminals)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228052/80483

Comment: Virtual consoles are, as far as I know, just another name for the ttys1-7 (or so) and are dealt with in the dupe's answer and in the link provided. What am I missing?

Comment: @terdon: Which namely of **five answers** (2 in ”Computer terminal and virtual console“ and 3 in “What is the exact…”) gives an introduction to virtual consoles comparable to one just posted by me?

Comment: [This one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/22222). If you feel your answer adds something more, just post it as an answer to the dupe target.

Comment: @terdon: have not a definite opinion about it, yourself?

Comment: Personally, no, I don't see that you're adding much to Gille's answer. You're giving the same basic information expressed differently. Still, some people might find yours clearer or more useful so feel free to post it. I just don't see any reason to reopen the dupe.

Comment: Ī̲ carefully read [Gilles’ answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/80483) in the “What is the exact…” thread. The only relevant piece found is *the name given to each particular tty can be “console”, ”virtual console”, ”virtual terminal”, and other variations* that definitely doesn’t answer the question asked in 2011 and wrongfully closed.

Comment: Who is this person "Ī̲" you are referencing to without prior introduction?

Answer (score 4):

The closed question will remain closed even if we decide it's not a dupe. It is asking 3 questions at once and that would make it too broad anyway.

In any case, if you feel you have something to add with respect to the distinction between "computer terminal" and "virtual console", by all means either add your own answer to the [dupe's target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) (you could always preface it with something like "I will focus on the differences between...), or post your own question, limiting its scope to only the differences between the terms and post the answer there.

Comment: Three questions at once? It’s true, but Ī̲ can answer this additional “text terminal / graphical terminal” stuff. Indeed, really Ī̲ ran once **two** `Xorg`s in two different VCs.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I'm sure you did, that's what they're there for after all :). My point is that 3 questions asked in a single post is already reason to close the post as too broad. There's no point in trying to get it reopened since--even if other people also agree that it isn't a dupe--it would still be closed as too broad. So, either post a new question, or add your answer to the dupe's target explaining that you will only focus on this part of the issue.

Comment: OK, then approve the http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/105784 edit, please.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi what? Why? Please leave that banner alone! It is pointing to the correct duplicate, why would you hijack that to make it point to your question?

Comment: You may hundred times say the word **DUPE**, but that doesn’t convince. Who was the moderator who closed the question with “duplicate”? Dunno.      If you don’t want me “hijacking” questions with near-expert-level answers (not generic VT/TTY fluff created without even reading the question up to its middle), then Ī̲ can withdraw with all disturbance (but with my expertise as well). Do you want it?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi why are you taking all this personally? You posted your question and a fine answer and all is good. What else do you want? And let's not spam the comments, please. Come into chat if you want to discuss this further.